# Plot n different graphs on the same plot with different colors in Python

Tags: python, plot, graph

I would like to plot n different graphs on the same plot with different color.
The problem I got is that I get lines between the different plots, and I don't get random color on the graph. I'm an beginner.

My Plot:

[image: Plot]

My Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import random
import numpy

list_y = []
list_x = []
counter = 0

# generate data
for i in range(0,5):
    for p in range(0,10):
        list_y.append(random.uniform(0.9,1.2))
         counter=counter+1
         list_x.append(counter)
         print(list_y)
         print(list_x)
    plt.plot(list_x, list_y,c=numpy.random.rand(3,)) 
    counter = 0

# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('x - axis') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('y - axis') 

# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('My first graph!') 

# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just misplaced the initialisations

```
list_y=[]
list_x=[]
```

before the line `for i in range(0,5):` rather than after it, hence finally a plot with the points of all 5 graphs is drawn over the preceding ones.